# Highcharts make pie chart goal value only 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, highcharts, user-experience

I am attempting to make my goal in the fiddle below any value other than 100%, but it will not accept my changes, it stays 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/erkin092/Yc3jF/1/

The code below is where i set the values

```
type: 'pie',
name: 'Goal',
size: '75%',
innerSize: '65%',
slicedOffset: 0,
data: [{
    name: 'Goal',
    y: 50,
    color: 'white'
}]
```

Comment: do you need something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3jF/2/

Comment: so how it should look like ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you have created a pie chart with only one slice.  No matter what size you set it as, 1 slice is always 100% of the pie.  Add a second at 50 and they should both show as 50.  Not sure how that fits your visual, but that's why it's always 100%.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt Pileggi said, you need to add another point so Highcharts will be able to calculate percentage. There is one problem - it would display second element in legend. Then you can disable legend for that specific series and add another one (fake) to display in legend. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yc3jF/5/

```
    {
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Goal',
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        size: '65%',
        innerSize: '65%',
        data: [{
            name: 'Goal',
            color: 'white'
        }]
    }, {
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Goal',
        size: '75%',
        innerSize: '65%',
        slicedOffset: 0,
        showInLegend: false,
        ignoreHiddenPoint: false,
        data: [{
            name: 'Goal',
            y: 50,
            color: 'white'
        },{
            name: 'Goal',
            y: 50,
            color: 'white',
            visible: false
        }]
     }
```